# How to use jq to return length of filtered array?

Tags: json, jq

My json file is called `my_locations.json` and contains an array called `locations`. I want to filter this array by all objects that have keys `location.is_shop` and `location.has_parking_space`. I then want to return the length of this filtered array.

Here is my attempt using the program `jq`:

```
$ jq ".locations[] | select(.is_shop and .has_parking_space) | length" my_locations.json
13
13
13
13
13
...
13
```

So it outputs the length of each location object in the array instead of the length of the filtered array.

How can I return the length of the filtered array?

Comment: It probably isn't the best way but you can just do `jq '[ ... ] | length'`

Comment: Because there might be a way to count number of elements without having to load the full array into memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `map` is what you need :

```
jq '.locations | map(select(has("is_shop") and has("has_parking_space"))) | length' my_locations.json
```

I think you should use function `has`, because you want to test `existence` of the keys, not the value.

Comment: works! and yes, `has` is what I want for existence of key instead of value of key

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the number of matching objects, you could efficiently just iterate over the original array, and count on a match (which avoids creating another array that is only used to extract its length).

```bash
reduce .locations[] as $loc (0;
  if all($loc; has("is_shop", "has_parking_space")) then . + 1 end
)
```

Note for the use of `if`: A missing `else` branch defaults to `else .`, which was introduced in jq 1.7. Prior to that version, you'd have to spell it out: `… then . + 1 else . end`.